# Identifying topology error with Javascript

Tags: javascript, topology

ArcGIS has tool to fix topology errors. Does any JavaScript gis package have similar function?

I have tried two packages.

1. OpenLayers has the function to build topology from geojson
2. TopoJson can transfer geojson to topojson

However, both of them simply build topology based on exact matched arc. They don't have ability to identify topology errors like a minor gap between two polygons.

Comment: Please added more details, what have you tried and researched?

Comment: I found this tool: https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper. It can clean topo errors but does not have a function to show the errors. Please comment if you have an idea